# Key Matching using shell

Tags: bash, shell

I wanted to see different type of answers I receive from you guys for the below problem. I am curious to see below problem being solved completely through array or any other matching (if there is any).

Below is the problem. Keeping `Name` as the key we need to print their various phone numbers in a line.

```
$cat input.txt

Name1, Phone1
Name2, Phone2
Name3, Phone1
Name4, Phone5
Name1, Phone2
Name2, Phone1
Name4, Phone1
```

O/P:
    $cat output.txt

```
Name1,Phone1,Phone2
Name2,Phone2,Phone1
Name3,Phone1
Name4,Phone5,Phone1
```

I solved the above problem but I wanted to see a solving technique perhaps one that is more effective than me. I am not an expert in shell still at a beginner level. My code below:

```
$cat keyMatchingfunction.sh
while read LINE; do
    var1=(echo "$LINE"|awk -F\, '{ print $1 }')
    matching_line=(grep "$var1" output.txt|wc -l)
    if [[ $matching_line -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo "$LINE" >> output.txt
    else
    echo $LINE is already present in output.txt
    grep -q -n "$var1" output.txt
    line_no=(grep -n "$var1" output.txt|cut -d: -f1)
    keymatching=(echo "$LINE"|awk -F\, '{ print $2 }')
    sed -i "$line_no s/$/,$keymatching/" output.txt
    fi
done
```

Comment: How did you solve this problem?

Comment: As common approach would be to sort the  file and pipe into a simple Awk script which collects input as long  as the first field stays the same.

Comment: @hjpotter92: Edited my post with code.. check

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
awk -F', ' '{a[$1]=a[$1]","$2}END{for(i in a) print i a[i]}' input.txt
```

Output:

```
Name1,Phone1,Phone2
Name2,Phone2,Phone1
Name3,Phone1
Name4,Phone5,Phone1
```

Comment: how the modification would be when the above code has no space in `input.txt` file....

Comment: Remove space after comma.

Answer (score 2):

With bash and sort:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A array         # define associative array

# read file input.txt to array
while IFS=", " read -r line number; do
  array["$line"]+=",$number"
done < input.txt

# print array
for i in "${!array[@]}"; do
  echo "$i${array[$i]}"
done | sort
```

Output:

```
Name1,Phone1,Phone2
Name2,Phone2,Phone1
Name3,Phone1
Name4,Phone5,Phone1
```