# Datamash: Transposing the column into rows based on group in bash

Tags: linux, awk, transpose

I have a tab delim file with a 2 columns like following

```
A 123
A 23
A 45
A 67
B 88
B 72
B 50
B 23
C 12
C 14
```

I want to transpose with the above data based on the first column like following

```
A 123 23 45 67
B 88  72 50 23
C 12 14
```

I tried the `datamash transpose < input-file.txt` but it didnt yield the output as expected.

Comment: `awk '{a[$1]=a[$1] " " $2}END{for(i in a) print i a[i]}' file` Derived from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32811764/3776858

Answer (score 3):

One `awk` version:

```
awk '{printf ($1!=f?"\n%s":" "$2),$0;f=$1}' file

A 123 23 45 67
B 88 72 50 23
C 12 14
```

With this version, you get on blank line, but should be fast and handle large data since no loop or array variable are used.

- `$1!=f?"\n%s":" "$2),$0` If first field is not equal `f`, print new line and all fields
- if `$1` = `f`, only print field 2.
- `f=$1` set `f` to first field

Answer (score 3):

```
datamash --group=1 --field-separator=' ' collapse 2 <file | tr ',' ' '
```

Output:

```
A 123 23 45 67
B 88 72 50 23
C 12 14
```

Input must be sorted, as in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;N;s/^((\S+)\s+.*)\n\2/\1/;ta;P;D' file
```

Append the next line and if the first field of the first line is the same as the first field of the second line, remove the newline and the first field of the second line. Print the first line in the pattern space and then delete it and the following newline and repeat.