# Extract unique words from a file and print the numbers associated with it in the same line tab separated in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell

My file is of the form shown below:

```
1: test
18: test
29: test
25: crazy
30: crazy
```

I want to ignore case and get the unique words in the file with their respective counts

The desired output should be :

```
test: 1 18 29
crazy: 25 30
```

Could someone guide how can this be done in Linux/Bash?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also your sample output is NOT clear, `crazy` AND `CRAZY` are not same and if you are using ignore-case then why `Test`'s first letter is capital BUT `crazy` is all small? Please clarify this more along with what oguz ismail said.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I have updated the post. My bad. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @oguzismail I have been trying to solve this problem for couple of hours and haven't got any further which is why I asked for guidance. I didn't ask for code. All I have been able to do is use CUT to get just the numbers but its not what I want. I am new to LInux.

Comment: This might help: [Key Matching using shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32810620/3776858)

Comment: @Cyrus Thanks for directing me.

Answer (score 2):

> Could someone guide how can this be done in Linux/Bash?

You can use awk's associative array to achieve that:

- convert the 2nd field into upper or lowercase
- build an associative array in awk
- use the result in the 1st step as key and append the 1st field into the array
- after all lines are processed by awk, you go thru your array, print out the keys and values

Answer (score 1):

This prints the desired output.

```
awk -F':' '{a[$2]=a[$2]" " $1}END{for(i in a) print i": " a[i]}' input_file.txt
```

Comment: I suggest the following variant: `awk -F': ' '{a[$2]=a[$2]" " $1}END{for(i in a) print i":" a[i]}' input_file.txt`

Comment: @Cyrus I don't see any difference