# Matching multiple values from matched file lines to one

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a question regarding Unix and shell. So my **input file** looks as follows:

```
path/filename ... username
path/filename2 ... username2
path/filename ... username2
...
```

and my desired goal, using ideally awk or sed, is to output something like:

```
filename username,username2
filename2 username2
```

so basically output one line for each unique file and print there all usernames, who opened them, all these values are stored in the input file so I'm just looking for an easiest way how parse them and do so.

Thanks in advance

Comment: We encourage questioners to show what they have tried so far to solve the problem themselves.

Comment: This might help: [Key Matching using shell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32810620/3776858)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this. First prepare the basename, then append usernames, finally print the array.

```
% awk '{sub(/.*\//, "", $1)
       arr[$1] != "" ? arr[$1]=arr[$1]","$NF : arr[$1]=$NF} 
       END{for(i in arr){print i,arr[i]}}' file
filename username,username2
filename2 username2
```

Answer (score 0):

I have taken the small sample and saved it as `dandys`.

```
awk '{i=gensub(/^.*\/(.*)$/,"\\1","1",$1);a[i]=a[i]""$NF","}END{for(i in a){gsub(/,$/,"",a[i]);print i,a[i]}}' dandys
filename username,username2
filename2 username2
```

In `i` we store the last path element of the first field, i.e. **filename***. We use `i` as an array index, and add the last field on each row, i.e. **username*** followed by a comma, to the respective a[filename]. After all input is processed we iterate over the array, trimming the last trailing comma, and printing the lot.